# Book on the financial circumstances and implications of mathematics

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm interested in statistics/estimations of the economic impact of mathematical/computer science research, say, how much difference the optimization of an algorithm can make in practice.

I also often wonder how the mathematical community receives and allocates resources. Why and for which purposes companies hire mathematicians. If and how companies support basic research. Which abstract formulations were necessary for which inventions and historical events.

So I'm not looking for a book on mathematical finance, I'm looking for the *finance of mathematics*. Is there a book that describes these processes more closely?